# How to call MockKKt.verify with a value for exactly?

Tags: kotlin, mockk

We're in the process of migrating classes we touch to Kotlin, so we need to mock Kotlin classes in Java test classes. We use `io.mockk:mockk:1.9.3`.

In order to verify invokation at least x times we have a wrapper method

```
public static void verify(MockkVerifier verifier, int atLeast) {
    MockKKt.verify(Ordering.UNORDERED, false, atLeast, Integer.MAX_VALUE, -1, 0, mockKVerificationScope -> {
        verifier.verify(mockKVerificationScope);
        return Unit.INSTANCE;
    });
}
```

which works fine. However for a method wrapping the functionality of exactly n invokations my only idea

```
public static void verifyExactly(MockkVerifier verifier, int exactly) {
    MockKKt.verify(Ordering.UNORDERED, false, exactly, Integer.MAX_VALUE, exactly, 0, mockKVerificationScope -> {
        verifier.verify(mockKVerificationScope);
        return Unit.INSTANCE;
    });
}
```

fails due to

```
io.mockk.MockKException: specify either atLeast/atMost or exactly

    at io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalCheckExactlyAtMostAtLeast(API.kt:153)
    at io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalVerify(API.kt:113)
    at io.mockk.MockKKt.verify(MockK.kt:139)
    [...]
```

when I invoke the method with `1` for `exactly`.

I can see that this is a good idea in Kotlin since I can use named arguments there, however I don't seem to be able to translate the solution to Java.

Answer (score 1):

The library does

```
if (exactly != -1 && (atLeast != 1 || atMost != Int.MAX_VALUE)) {
    throw MockKException("specify either atLeast/atMost or exactly")
}
```

So, 1 has to be specified in order to make `atLeast` be ignored.